# PowerShell using a variable in quotes within a command

Tags: powershell, variables, quotes, variable-expansion

I have this which works (triple double quotes are not a mistake; it works exactly like this)—concentrate on the `Start-Process` part:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred -WorkingDirectory "$lettre_disque" -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process """D:\WD Drive Unlock.exe""" -verb runas}'
```

Now I'm simply trying to replace the string `D:\WD Drive Unlock.exe` with a variable named `$chemin_fichier` which contains the exact same text (`D:\WD Drive Unlock.exe`).

I'm trying:

```
"""$chemin_fichier"""

""$chemin_fichier""

"$chemin_fichier"

""""$chemin_fichier""""
```

Nothing works...

How do I get that variable to show up? This command is pretty confusing. What is the right combination? Do I have to escape something or?

Comment: -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -command &{Start-Process """D:\WD Drive Unlock.exe""" -verb runas}' -f $chemin_fichier)

Comment: My aim is to remove D:\WD...since the letter is variable, the correct path is stored in $chemin_fichier, how do i place $chemin_fichier so it replaces that string? Like :  
-ArgumentList ('-noprofile -command &{Start-Process """$chemin_fichier"""

Comment: Woops...didn't finish editing it:  
-ArgumentList ('-noprofile -command &{Start-Process """{0}""" -verb runas}' -f $chemin_fichier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break your command into pieces using splatting:

```
$chemin_fichier = 'D:\WD Drive Unlock.exe'

$ArgList = @{
    FilePath = 'powershell'
    Credential = $cred
    WorkingDirectory = $lettre_disque
    ArgumentList = @(
        '-NoProfile'
        '-Command'
        "`"Start-Process -FilePath '$chemin_fichier' -Verb runas`""
    )
}
Start-Process @ArgList
```

Wrapping your command in a script block was unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it was a nightmare working with the one line command. That syntax is hardcore though haha. I'll get used to it one day, MUCH appreciated.

Comment: @Rakha Yeah, working with `Start-Process` arguments is rough at first.

Answer (score 1):

I use a command with parameters like this, which will replace `store:Schema="abcd"` with an empty string. It's critical to escape `"` to `""` or `""""`, and you should give it a try. Test and modify to ensure the script works:

```
powershell -Command "$varStr='store:Schema=""abcd""""'; $filePath='%~dp0SomeFolder\SomeFile.txt'; (gc $filePath) -replace $varStr, '' | Out-File $filePath"
```